# c program crashes while trying to open a file with variable filename

Tags: c

As stated in the title, i ask for the user to provide the filename and i use `gets` to save it in `str`. Then i try to access the file using the name and the program crashes.

```
int openFile(FILE *fp){
    puts("What's the name of the file (and format) to be accessed?");
    char str[64];
    gets(str);  
    fp = fopen((const char *)str, 'r');
    ...
    return 0;
```

In main:

```
FILE *fp; // file pointer

openFile(fp);
```

The filename i enter (data.txt) is indeed in the same directory as the rest of the project so that should not be the problem. I've tried testing if the file is opened correctly (which it should) but it keeps crashing right after i give the name.

Comment: The second parameter to `fopen` must be a string. not a character: `fopen(str, "r");` Note the double quotes. (Warnings should have told yu about the type mismatch. Activate them.)

Comment: Never use `gets()`. The manual page explains why (impossible to guard against buffer overflow).

Comment: @abligh thanks for pointing that out, will fgets do the trick?

Comment: `fgets` will help, but the problem (unless you were typing more than 63 characters) is actually that you are passing a character rather than a string as the second parameters, as @MOehm pointed out before I could get there (along with the fact that compiling with `-Wall` would make this type of error obvious).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `fp = fopen(str, "r");`, because `fopen()` expects `mode` as a `char *` pointing to a string, rather than a single `char`.

Also, since parameters in C are **passed by value**, your `fp` won't get modified after `openFile()` is called. To get it work, you'll have to rewrite it, and call it by `openFile(&fp);`. Here is an example:

```
void openFile(FILE **fp) {
    puts("What's the name of the file (and format) to be accessed?");
    char str[64];
    fgets(str, 64, stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';  
    *fp = fopen(str, "r");
}
```

`fgets()` is used to provide buffer overflow protection.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you are trying to set an argument passed by value in a function and expect the value to be changed outside. This can't work.

Currently you have:

```
void openFile(FILE* fp) {
  fp = ...
}

int main()
{
  FILE* fp;
  openFile(fp);
}
```

But `fp` in `main()` is passed as a pointer by value. Which means that inside `openFile` you are setting a local variable, while the passed one is not modified.

To solve the problem you can:

- directly return a `FILE*` from `openFile`
- accept a pointer to pointer argument to be able to set it, eg `void openFile(FILE** fp)` and then `openFile(&fp)`

Mind that the second argument of `fopen` is a `const char*` not a single `char`, `"r"` should be used.

Comment: Whilst true, that's not what's causing `fopen` to crash.