# C standard prohibition on warnings by default

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Seeing yet another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664754/c-program-crashes-while-trying-to-open-a-file-with-variable-filename) the answer to which would have been obvious had the questioner compiled with `-Wall` got me thinking.

Is there a 'C standard' based reason why `-Wall` cannot be enabled by default by the compiler?

As far as I know none of the major compilers do this (and certainly historically none of them did it), and I'd like to know whether this is adherence to the standard, or some other reason (inertia, back compatibility or whatever). Speculating as to the other reason is probably off-topic (opinion based), but I think asking whether a standard requires this behaviour is on-topic (factual).

Comment: The language standard does not have a normative notion of a "warning".

Comment: According to the [`gcc` manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options), `-Wall` enables ".. all the warnings about constructions that **some** users consider questionable" – (my emph.).

Comment: What you really want is `-pedantic` and `-std=c11` (or whatever language you want). That makes the compiler reject things which are actually ill-formed.

Comment: @RadLexus sure. But that wouldn't prevent the users that did not find them questionable ignoring them or using `-Wswitch-the-lights-off-so-I-can-complain-about-bumping-into-things` or whatever.

Comment: I am not arguing against you :) I'd rather see `-Wall` enabled by default and have a separate switch `-WtrustMeIknowWhatITypedBecauseIDidSoIntentionally`.

Comment: @KerrekSB But the language standard does have the notation of diagnostics, which translate into warnings. There are a few occasions, where the C standard requires the compiler to print diagnostics.

Comment: @Leandros: Diagnostics are typically required for *ill-formed* programs. This is in contrast with ill-formed programs that "require no diagnostic", e.g. those with ODR violations.

Comment: The compilers don't conform by default because too many people would complain . There is a huge amount of code out there that doesn't comply with the standard and relies on historical behaviour of the compiler.  A pet peeve of mine is the compiler saying "warning" instead of "error" for code that performs conversions that are illegal or require a cast. E.g. pointer to integer and vice versa, it misleads beginners .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a 'C standard' based reason why `-Wall` cannot be enabled by default by the compiler?

I think that the answer to that is that no standard-based reason.  The behavior of compiler switches is outside the scope of a language standard.

Beyond that, a compiler is (generally speaking) not required to produce diagnostics for things that are not specified to be compilation errors, so requiring such diagnostics be output "by default" is nonsensical.

---

And to be clear, these general statements apply in the case of the C language.

Answer (score 5):

Quoted from N1570 Annex I:

> 1 An implementation may generate warnings in many situations, none of
>   which are specified as part of this International Standard.

This implies that warnings are non-compulsory to compilers, so I don't think there would be any "C standard" based reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the reason mentioned above, that the standard does not have specifications on warnings, make Wall default would be more a obstacle for many people because there are warnings that you actually don't want to turn on from time to time, such as warnings on unused variables/functions etc.
If you want to make it "by default", you can alias the compiler of your choice, take gcc as example, add following in your bashrc:

```
alias gcc="gcc -Wall"
```

Comment: This isn't convincing. GCC has flags to turn off warnings, so you'd never be "stuck". Turning on warnings by default would be much, much better.